# Сортировка списка по другому списку

Tags: java

Есть `LinkedList<ClassXXX>`, `ClassXXX` содержит множество полей, одно из которых `Integer Id`.

Есть `ArrayList<Integer>`, который содержит `Id` от `ClassXXX`.

Нужно отсортировать элементы `LinkedList` в той же самой последовательности, как они расположены в `ArrayList`. Если в `ArrayList` нет `Id`, которое есть в первом списке, то такие элементы располагаются в конце `LinkedList`. Также `Id` может быть во втором списке, но не быть в первом. Сортируется исключительно первый список `LinkedList<ClassXXX>`.

Подскажите, в какую сторону смотреть, чтобы это реализовать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно завести [`HashMap<Integer, ClassXXX>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html), в которой ключами будут `id`, а значениями — экземпляры `ClassXXX`, с таким `id`. Далее, заводим новый `LinkedList<ClassXXX>`, проходимся по `ArrayList<Integer>` (список айдишек), [получаем из `HashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#get-java.lang.Object-) экземпляр класса `ClassXXX`, с таким `id` и добавляем его в новый `LinkedList<ClassXXX>`.

Осталось добавить в конец нового `LinkedList<ClassXXX>` элементы, `id` которых не нашлись в `ArrayList<Integer>`. Можно сделать это так: при проходе по списку айдишек [удалять из `HashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#remove-java.lang.Object-) записи, а в конце добавить [все значения из `HashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#values--) в конец нового `LinkedList<ClassXXX>`.

```
class Main {
    static class Item {
        int id;

        Item(int id) {
            this.id = id;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // пример входных данных
        ArrayList<Integer> ids = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(4, 2, 1));
        LinkedList<Item> items = new LinkedList<>(Arrays.asList(
            new Item(1),
            new Item(2),
            new Item(3)
        ));

        // добавляем каждый item в Map
        HashMap<Integer, Item> idsToItems = new HashMap<>();
        for (Item item : items) {
            idsToItems.put(item.id, item);
        }

        LinkedList<Item> itemsSorted = new LinkedList<>();
        for (Integer id : ids) {
            if (idsToItems.containsKey(id)) {
                Item item = idsToItems.get(id);
                itemsSorted.add(item);
                idsToItems.remove(id);
            }
        }
        for (Item item : idsToItems.values()) {
            itemsSorted.add(item);
        }

        for (Item item : itemsSorted) {
            System.out.println(item.id);
        }
    }
}
```

[Ideone](https://ideone.com/tc5clO)

Comment: Спасибо за идею и ее реализацию! Правильно ли я понимаю, что с компаратором тут не выкрутиться?

Comment: @Алёнка, с компаратором можно, но это либо будет `O(n^2 * logn)` решение (если только сортировка с компаратором и ничего больше), либо `O(n * logn)` решение (если как в ответе завести `HashMap`). Решение в ответе работает за `O(n)` (то есть за линейное время), поэтому я написал именно его.

Comment: а Вы можете код с сортировкой с компаратором написать? Так...на будущее...

Comment: @Алёнка, извините, сейчас не могу, задайте новый вопрос, в котором так и напишите, что хотите решение с компаратором, пусть оно и будет работать за `O(n^2 * logn)`. Уверен, кто-нибудь ответит.